# For some reason none of the events work in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using listeners or .on method don't work.

The only thing that worked for me was using handler for buttons.

Example of a code (it doesn't work in the fiddle and in latest chrome):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34p5

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click Me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'I was clicked!');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because modern toolkit button hasn't `click` event

Use [tap](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#event-tap) event.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34p6)

Comment: Thank you so much you are a god

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
text: 'Click Me',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
handler: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'I was clicked!');
}});
```